Does the sides and diagonals of a convex quadrilateral inscribed on a ellipse satisfy the triangle inequality only if its eccentricity $< 0.89$?
Convex quadrilaterals are drawn with its vertices on the circumference of a fixed ellipse. In every such quadrilateral, using the two diagonals $d_1,d_2$ and one of the four sides $a,b,c,d$ we have the four triplets $(d_1,d_2,a)$, $(d_1,d_2,b)$, $(d_1,d_2,c)$ and $(d_1,d_2,d)$. One or more or none of these four triplets may satisfy the triangle inequality. What is the maximum eccentricity of the ellipse such that at least one of these four triplets always satisfy the triangle inequality?
In the case of a circle, in this question it was proved that we can always find not one but at least two such adjacent sides.

This is not true in general for an ellipse and I found several counter examples of quadrilaterals on ellipses where none of the four triplets satisfied the triangle inequality. However an interesting pattern emerged out of the counter examples that is in all the counter examples, eccentricity of the ellipse was more than $0.89$. The evidence suggests that there is a critical value of the eccentricity $E \approx 0.89$ above which that is no guarantee that at least one of the three triplets will satisfy the triangle inequality.

Conjecture: If every quadrilateral in a fixed ellipse has the property that at it always has at least one side $a$ such that the triplet $(d_1,d_2,a)$ satisfy the triangle inequality then the the eccentricity of the ellipse is less than $E \approx 0.89$.

If the eccentricity is greater than $E$ than all the four triplets may fail the triangle inequality. I am looking for a proof or disproof of this conjecture.

If $d_1 \le d_2$ are the lengths of the diagonals and $a$ any of the sides, a short view on the question gives me the feeling that $d_1 \le d_2+a$ is evident. But surely, I have misunderstood something...

@JeanMarie Assuming $d_1 \le d_2$, for the triplet $(d_1,d_2,a)$ satisfy the triangle inequality, we must have $d_1 + a \ge d_2$, $d_1+d_2 \ge a$ and $d_2+a \ge d_1$. Of these, the last two inequalities are trivial so we only need to find under what conditions $d_1 + a \ge d_2$ is satisfied. So the question is asking if $d_1 + a \ge d_2$ given $d_1 \le d_2$ then what is the maximum possible eccentricity?

@NilotpalSinha: To be clear ... You want to show that if and only if every convex quadrilateral inscribed in a given ellipse has the property that its diagonals and some side form a triangle, then (and only then) that ellipse has eccentricity at most $0.89$-ish. Correct? ... It's pretty easy to find lots of individual quads with the triangle property that can be circumscribed by conics (including parabolas and hyperbolas) of larger eccentricity.

@NilotpalSinha: Typo "side side". :) ... Also, to JeanMarie's comment: When you write "satisfy the triangle inequality", you mean "satisfy all three aspects of the triangle inequality"; eg, $x\leq y+z$, $y\leq z+x$, $z\leq x+y$. (To me, it's just simpler to say "form a triangle".)

@Blue Yes correct, form a triangle

Conic through intercepts such that $\alpha \gamma, \beta \delta<0$:
$$
\left(
    \frac{x}{\alpha}-1
  \right)
  \left(
    \frac{x}{\gamma}-1
  \right)+
  \left(
    \frac{y}{\beta}-1
  \right)
  \left(
    \frac{y}{\delta}-1
  \right)=1+2\lambda xy$$

For a fixed combination of $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta$, we could only have minimal eccentricity only.

In particular,
$$\lambda=\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{\alpha \beta \gamma \delta}}$$
give a pair of parabolae, namely
$$\left[
  \left(
    \frac{x}{\alpha}-1
  \right)
  \left(
    \frac{x}{\gamma}-1
  \right)+
  \left(
    \frac{y}{\beta}-1
  \right)
  \left(
    \frac{y}{\delta}-1
  \right)-1
\right]^2=
\frac{4x^2y^2}{\alpha \beta \gamma \delta}$$
which has eccentricity of $1$.

Eccentricity $e$ of general conic $ax^2+2hxy+by^2+2gx+2fy+c=0$

$$\frac{1-e^2}{(2-e^2)^2} = \frac{ab-h^2}{(a+b)^2}$$
Minimal eccentricity

For $\alpha \gamma < \beta \delta < 0$,

$$e=1-\frac{\beta \delta}{\alpha \gamma}$$

For $\beta \delta < \alpha \gamma < 0$,

$$e=1-\frac{\alpha \gamma}{\beta \delta}$$

$\alpha \gamma=\beta \delta$ gives a cyclic quadrilateral


Recall for logic:
\begin{array}{|c|c|} \hline
  \text{Conditional statement} &  P\to Q \\
  \text{Converse} & Q\to P \\
  \text{Contrapositive} & \neg Q\to \neg P \\
  \text{Inverse} & \neg P \to \neg Q \\ \hline
\end{array}

Contrapositive is equivalent to the original conditional statement (if $P$ then $Q$).
Converse and Inverse are equivalent.
Converse also holds implying $P$ and $Q$ are necessary and sufficient conditions (if and only if).


To clarify, what does your post show? Are you supporting OP's conjecture?

Your conjecture seems to be incorrect.  For fixed intercepts, there is minimal eccentricity instead.

Whether intercepts satisfy those triangle inequalities or not, we always could have parabolae pair formed.

That is consistent to what @Blue commented before.

@NgChungTak I am not clear what exactly do you meant by "there is a minimal eccentricity". If eccentricity is greater that $0.89$ is the guaranteed that we can still find at least one such triangle.

@NilotpalSinha Thinking about the degree of freedom.  Or alternatively dependencies among different variables.  Note that $d_1=|\alpha-\gamma|$, $d_2=|\beta-\delta|$ and $a=\sqrt{\alpha^2+\beta^2}$, etc.  With fixed $\alpha$ ,$\beta$, $\gamma$ and $\delta$ implies fixed $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, $d_1$ and $d_2$.  We  could vary $\lambda$ without upper limit of the eccentricities $e$.

@NilotpalSinha See the Recall for logic at the end of my answer.
